The off topic dialog should allow us to tag a question as belonging on another site
When a user asks a question that is clearly better on a programming site like stack exchange the natural thing to do is to flag it as closed as "Off topic because" and then "belongs on another site".
The issue is that the only other site that is listed is the quantitative finance meta site.
At a very minimum stack exchange should be on that list.
This would allow programming specific questions like What are the parameters of the function PORTVAR in Matlab?
to be ported to stack exchange where they belong.


I'm not sure whether I agree about your assessment about this question but quite surprised you're not able to suggest a move to an arbitrary site. I can but I'm a mod, can someone confirm this?

@Bob, I've included a screen shot so you can see what the average person has to deal with:)

I assume you meant to be ported to StackOverflow, right?

@SRKX yes I meant StackOverflow:)

Migration to other sites is done automatically so I understand only moderators can trigger them; it can't result from 5 close votes from users.
I guess it also helps if 5 different users choose different site to migrate it to...
You can always flag the post and we'll get the notification and do what's necessary.
Besides, regarding the question you're referring to, I think it is acceptable here because it's not in fact a programming question like "how do you compute the variance of a portfolio in matlab?" but it asks for conceptual details. I'm not saying it would be off-topic on StackOverflow, but I think there is a good chance it might be answered more easily here.
